# How do I simulate a keyboard press using an UI button?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to port a runner game I made for PC onto Android, so I already have full player control set up using the Space bar, Up arrow, Down arrow, and s button so I wanted to be able to just create UI buttons that simulate a keyboard keypress.

Is there any way for me to, for instance, create a script that states that `OnButtonPress` trigger a keyboard key such as the Space key for jumping?

Comment: It is supposed to be unity 2d btw

Comment: Easy way is to split your actions into functions that you can call from either event.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of simulating inputs, you can split the work out into functions that can be called from either event.

Example for jump-

```
private void DoJump()
{
    // Jump logic here
}
```

**PC Input**

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        DoJump();
    }
}
```

**Mobile Input**

```
[SerializeField]
private Button jumpButton; // <- assign this in inspector

private void Awake()
{
    jumpButton.onClick.AddListener(() => DoJump());
}
```

Another alternative to this setup is using the new input system.  The new input system allows you to map inputs from different sources to the same action.  [New Input System](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/QuickStartGuide.html).

This is my preferred way of handling inputs now when controller, mouse/keyboard, and joystick support are required.

For an existing project where you have everything working as expected, it is often easier and less work to use the first example above.

Comment: private void DoJump()  
    {  
        if (isGrounded == true)  
        {  
            RB.AddForce(Vector2.up * JumpForce);  
            isGrounded = false;  
        }  
  
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))  
        {  
            DoJump();  
        }  
  
        jumpButton.onClick.AddListener(() => DoJump());  
    }  
I tried this but this cant have been what you ment @hjinxbassit ? the format isnt working i dont know why

Comment: I have update the answer to better reflect how it would be used in your script.  Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: @hjinxbassit yes i did that and it says that the name "jumButton" doesn't exist in the current context

Comment: Add the button you will use for jumping.  Create a variable called jumpButton in your script (public or with [SerializeField]), and assign the button to that variable.